# Is there no auto mapping from JSON to a model class like in C# or Java?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Currently for testing we map our json as follows

```
class Order{

  String orderId;
  String customerName;
  String fulfilmentStartTime;
  String fulfilmentEndTime;
  int totalItems;
  String shortCode;
  String orderNumber;
  String status;

  Order({
    this.orderId,
    this.customerName,
    this.fulfilmentStartTime,
    this.fulfilmentEndTime,
    this.totalItems,
    this.shortCode,
    this.orderNumber,
    this.status
  });

  Order.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
    : orderId = json['id'],
      customerName = json['customer']["firstName"] + " " + json['customer']["lastName"],
      fulfilmentStartTime = json['fulfillment']["startTime"],
      fulfilmentEndTime = json['fulfillment']["endTime"],
      totalItems = json['totalItems'],
      shortCode = json['shortCode'],
      orderNumber = json['orderNumber'],
      status = json['status']
      ;

}
```

We currently have tried the combination of json_serializable package and build_runner but we will prefer to have a direct way to do it other than this.

We have a really large json set much bigger than this that might need to be updated a lot.

Needing to update this map each time, we need to add or remove a property can lead to many issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to parse json to model is create the method manually like you share. There is a [webpage](https://app.quicktype.io/) where setting json object can get model statement.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively there isn't. While Dart has reflection implemented via [dart:mirrors](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-mirrors/dart-mirrors-library.html) it is banned for Flutter as it has few implications on the runtime.

You can use build_runner or any other code generator like [Dart Data Class Generator
for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BendixMa.dart-data-class-generator).

This will probably change once static metaprogramming comes to Dart, but at this moment it is in early stages so don't expect it too soon. Progress can be tracked on [the GitHub issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1482)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a package like `json_serializable`

Link: https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/deep_pick

Simplifies manual JSON parsing with a type-safe API.

- No dynamic, no manual casting
- Flexible inputs types, fixed output types
- Useful parsing error messages

  ```
   final json = jsonDecode(response.body);  
    // Parse a full object using a fromPick factory constructor  
    final CounterApiStats stats = CounterApiStats.fromPick(pick(json).required());
  ```